# How can I detect or trigger an event when text in <p> tag is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger an event when text inside a `<p>` tag has changed. I thought to use `change()` but I realize it's meant for form input elements.

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  $('p').html("done");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
<button id="click">click to change</button>
```

Comment: To track changes in DOM elements, you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Why not just call whatever you need to inside the `click` handler?

Comment: I think you can use this: `$('#test').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`MutationObserver()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) below is a demo.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p')

function changeText(){
  p.textContent = "red";
}


var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

var observer = new MutationObserver((list) => {
  console.log(list[0].target.textContent);
});

observer.observe(p, config);
```

```html
<div>
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
<button id="click" onclick="changeText()">click to change</button>
```

Comment: Typescrit throw me this: Argument of type 'HTMLParagraphElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'. 
How can I correct that problem? Apparently the tag p is not a node.

Comment: @carl The querySelector actually returns a Node not a paragraph element. You can type 'p' explicitly.